# iScroll - Uncaught ReferenceError: myScroll is not defined in index and Stale touch event ACTION_DOWN received from webcore

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll4, iscroll, referenceerror

I use iScroll in my levels page but somehow my editor complain ReferenceError in my index page (another page) which I didnt use iScroll. I search 'myScroll' in my index but there is no such word in my index. Because of the error, my iScroll that work in the browser does not work in the Android emulator.

```
09-04 08:31:06.249: E/Web Console(942): Uncaught ReferenceError: myScroll is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:1
```

If I swipe in the emulator, it produces

```
09-04 15:58:57.318: W/webview(3045): Stale touch event ACTION_DOWN received from webcore; ignoring
```

index.html (I didnt use iScroll)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>App Name</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>        
<div id="mainContainer" data-role="page" >
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="homeLinks">
    <img id="icon" src="css/images/icon.png">
    <p><a href="#level" data-role="button" data-theme="a">level</a></p>

    </div>   
  </div>        
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

level page (page I used iScroll)

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" >
<header data-role="header">  
    <a href="settings.html" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-right">Settings</a>  
    <h1>Study Levels</h1>  
</header>
<div id="level1" data-role="content">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="scroller">
             <ul id="thelist">
                  <li><img src="css/images/level1.png"/></li>
                  <li><img src="css/images/level2.png"/></li>
                  <li>zz</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>      

<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="prev" onclick="myScroll.scrollToPage('prev', 0);return false">&larr; prev</div>
      <ul id="indicator">
        <li class="active">1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
      <div id="next" onclick="myScroll.scrollToPage('next', 0);return false">next &rarr;</div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/ender.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="iscroll-lite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         $(document).ready(function () {

        this.myScroll = $('#wrapper').iScroll({
        snap: true,
        momentum: false,
       hScrollbar: false,
        onScrollEnd: function () {
          document.querySelector('#indicator > li.active').className = '';
          document.querySelector('#indicator > li:nth-child(' + (this.currPageX+1) + ')').className = 'active';
        }
        })
    })
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

----Update------

Having another look, $ in $('#wrapper').iScroll... is from ender not jQuery and i believe thats causing a conflict.

So you might wanna create a closure, something like this:

```
  (function($){
      $(document).ready(function() {
           this.myScroll = $('#wrapper').iScroll({
           //custom options here 
           });
      });
  })(ender);
```

And because 'this' inside enders document.ready function points to window object,

you can simply pass inline event handeler like this:

```
 <div id="prev" onclick="myScroll.scrollToPage('prev', 0);return false"> stuff </div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I follow the examples of ender from the official website. When I change my codes (the jquery part) it become cannot be swiped. It gets : 09-04 14:27:14.318: E/Web Console(2594): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'scrollToPage' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:1

Comment: Appologies for reading your question incorrectly, updated my answer above. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You have bound the `myScroll` variable to the document. So either you have to us it by calling `document.myScroll`, or you can bind it to the `window` by replacing `this` with `window` (Or just remove it) so it becomes:

```
window.myScroll = $('#wrapper') ...
```

and then you can call it as a regular variable.

Comment: So I have to change to 
window.myScroll = $('#wrapper').iScroll ?

Comment: Getting  Cannot call method 'scrollToPage' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:1. Can you show me a more complete set of snippets? Thank you.